# Use Global parameters in Room Queries

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I want to define and use global parameters in queries because they are common between some queries, I have global array of RoleTypes:

```
private final static RoleType[] ROLE_TYPES = new RoleType[]{RoleType.MEMBER, RoleType.ADMIN};
```

RoleType is an enum and I want to use it in queries like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM dialog WHERE dialog_role = " + ROLE_TYPES)
public abstract List<Dialog> getMyItems();

@Query("SELECT * FROM dialog WHERE dialog_type =:dialogType AND dialog_role = " + ROLE_TYPES)
public abstract List<Dialog> getMyItems(DialogType dialogType);
```

I get an error: `Attribute value must be constant`. If I pass array as a parameter to the function problem solved:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM dialog WHERE dialog_role =:roleTypes")
public abstract List<Dialog> getMyItems(RoleType[] roleTypes);
```

but I don't want to repeat passing parameter and I want to handle it in dao queries.

Comment: Um, what would it mean to have an array of enum values on the right side of an equality comparison?

Comment: Yes, type of dialog_role in db is an enum. I want to use an array global variable of it in dao queries and don't pass it as an parameter to the several common function for cleaner code.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, in that I don't need to pass the enum string value to the method, I just need to use it as a filter, yet I want it to survive refactoring.